# Will my Facebook friends see if I comment on a Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Let's say I liked a business page on Facebook and commented on their status, will my friends see this on their news feed? I'd like to comment on some Facebook Pages I follow without letting my whole friend list know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my Facebook friends actually liked a page earlier today and posted a comment on one of the page's statuses.

When I went to my News Feed (set to "Most Recent"), it told me that my friend liked the page, but it didn't tell me that he posted a comment on one of their status updates.  When I switched my News Feed to "Top Stories", it didn't tell me about his like or his comment.  So depending on how your friends have their news feeds set up, they might see if you've liked a page, but they won't see if you've posted a comment on a page.

*However*, I also have my friend in the Close Friends list, and when I clicked on the Close Friends list, it told me about both of the things he did - that he liked the page and also that he posted a comment on the page.  So if any of your friends have you in their Close Friends list, then they'll be able to see all your likes and comments when they click on the Close Friends list.